# How can I play 3gp in video.js

Tags: html, flash, video, video.js, 3gp

I am trying to play a 3gp video by using video.js, Is it possible to play 3gp with flash fallback in video.js?
I am getting error:`Sorry no compatible source and playback technology is found.`
Please give me some good advice or learning resources.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to play 3gp with flash fallback in video.js?

Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872721/videojs-where-is-current-information-on-supported-video-formats-and-their-brows) from a similar question on SO.

For learning resources please visit the [official site](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/index.md).

Some more interesting posts that could be helpful are as following:
[Issue with the flash fallback of VideoJs, how to make it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644444/issue-with-the-flash-fallback-of-videojs-how-to-make-it-work)

[Configure VideoJS Flash fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465292/configure-videojs-flash-fallback)